# PHP VERIFYHOST error :unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, local

When I enable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER i get this error from curl:
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I read that i should include something to the php.ini file but i do not have access to that file because it's not a self hosted site. I alredy purchased ssl certification for my site and the host said that they will set everything.

Where could be the problem at my site or at the host?

Comment: Try calling your website in the browser and check the SSL Certificate.

Comment: i's said that the connection is not safe

Comment: You might have to talk about this issue with the technical support from your host. The installation/configuration of the ssl certificate might not be completed yet.

Comment: Okay thanks i will give it a try but i purchased it nearly a month ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to talk about this issue with the technical support from your host. The installation/configuration of the ssl certificate might not be completed yet.